# App Engine Flexible cron is terminated after 120 seconds

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, cron, app-engine-flexible

My App Engine Flexible cron sometimes takes more than 120 seconds. So, whenever it exceeds 120 seconds, app engine throws `502` error. It doesn't terminate my nodejs task, it only terminates the http request started by App Engine Cron job.

[image]

There is one value `240 seconds`, I didn't understand where its coming from. I guess this is a retry request. It would be helpful if anyone can highlight this as well.

As per App Engine documentation, a cron can run for an hour. Is this true for http requests started by cron job as well?

To be clear, I want to run my cron for more than 120 seconds and http request to be active for 1 hour.

Comment: Open HTTP connections to an App Engine application are closed after 120 seconds of inactivity, which would be the reason the application returns an error after that time. It would be interesting to know the purpose of your cron job and why does it have tasks that would involve HTTP requests open for up to 1 hour. I assume that you want to keep the cron job open for as long as the tasks involving your HTTP requests are active (1 hour in this case). Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @RodrigoC., purpose of my cron job is to bring data in from an external application. My cron job usually finishes in 120 seconds but sometimes (based on what data is coming) it takes more than that. I can't bring the execution time below this considering the number of operations it performs. 
I want to keep http request open because I want GAE to recognize whether my cron job has succeeded or not. If I run my cron job asynchronously then GAE considers it as a successful job but if I run synchronously it shows me timeout after 120 seconds. 
Although I have moved to Kubernetes Engine now.

Answer (score 0):

Even though you have switched to Kubernetes Engine, I would like to take the chance and clarify the purpose of cron jobs here.

As it is stated in the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/scheduling-jobs-with-cron-yaml), cron jobs are used to perform jobs at regular time intervals. They involve invoking a URL through an HTTP request and run for up to 60 minutes while respecting the [request's own limitations](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/how-requests-are-handled#quotas_and_limits).

Some good uses for cron jobs: sending report emails on a daily basis, update cached data at regular time intervals or update summary information every hour. When a task involves obtaining external information, especially when there is a large number of operations involved that may exceed the time an HTTP connection remains open, or when there are different types of data that are coming from the external application, I would not consider it a good use of cron jobs.

If you are using Kubernetes now, and consider it to be more useful for the tasks you need to perform, go ahead and continue with it.